# Maven Install error after deleteing .m2 folder

Tags: java, spring, maven

I try to run maven install on my project with some dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringBatchSample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>SpringBatchSample</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
          </dependency>


          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch unit test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/org.springframework.batch.core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.springframework.batch.core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <finalName>SpringBatchSample</finalName>
     <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <!-- Eclipse project -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Always download and attach dependencies source code -->
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <!-- Avoid type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 -->
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
        </configuration>
         </plugin>

          <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>

          <execution>

            <id>purge-local-dependencies</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <!-- <goals>
              <goal>purge-local-repository</goal>
            </goals> -->
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>[groupId1]:[artifactId1]</exclude>
                <exclude>[groupId2]:[artifactId2]</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>



    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
    </build>


</project>
```

the first time run the project mvn install it's run just fine (BUILD SUCCESS) but the second time ("after I make some changes in the code(pom.xml)") I try to run mvn install and maven throw "error in opening zip file".

```
ERROR] error: error reading D:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.1.3.RELEASE\spring-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] error: error reading D:\Maven\Repository\org\apache\commons\com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging\1.1.1\com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading D:\Maven\Repository\org\aopalliance\com.springsource.org.aopalliance\1.0.0\com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error: error reading D:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\org.springframework.core\2.5.6.A\org.springframework.core-2.5.6.A.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

after i referred some site i deleted the .m2 folder but repeatedly im getting the same error.

what can be the problem if any one help me to resolve this error

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the changes that you have done in pom?

Comment: The above mentioned jars seems to be corrupt. Try deleting those and replace with the new ones downloading manually from the official site.

Comment: i have just added the spring related dependency only

Comment: Check the sha1 checksums of the artifacts...and turn https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories checksum policy to failure...after done that delete you .m2/repository cache and rebuild...Removed the eclipse plugin cause it's retired and remove the purge of the .m2/repository by your pom file...

Comment: could you  please elaborate this answer because im new to this technology.

Comment: Try removing .m2/repository again and build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rebuild the project with maven ? ( maven => update => force .. )

Answer (score 0):

You make sure .m2 on path D:\Maven\Repository\org in settings.xml file.
Because **error reading D:\Maven\Repository\org\springframework\org.springframework.core\2.5.6.A\org.springframework.core-2.5.6.A.jar;**,

The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository. If you changed it you should be sure the path is correct.